# Unexpected error connecting vtiger with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I am currently getting this error in **vtiger** installation wizard (step 4).

```
MySQL Server should be configured with:  
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I am using shared `PHP 7.2` `MySQL 5.7` hosting and **adminer** says that `sql_mode` is set to

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

---

**Here comes the question**
Is this behaviour really related to `sql_mode` setting? Do I have to contact my hosting provider or there is there an override?

Comment: Edit you my.cnf file and remove the configurations not required

Comment: Yes, you have to contact your hosting provider to either downgrade MySql to lower version that supports full group by etc or you can ask them to change the settings accordingly.

Comment: I guess, any version of MySql lower than 5.7 should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Penguine I don't have access to conf files

Comment: @Penguine thanks! so is it version specific? I can set the version while creating the database...

Comment: Yes bro!....Greater than 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to a new **mariadb 10** database solved the problem.

Changing **MySQL** version to **<5.7** as stated in comments should therefore work as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu - Run command:

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Add the following part to the bottom:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Run command to restart MySQL Service:

`sudo service mysql restart`

You will also need to change Database Collation to `utf8_general_ci` in phpmyadmin.

Done !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pay attention to the port Mysql is using, if you are using Wampserver, By default the new versions install MariaDB first, and MySQL second so MariaDB get the port 3306 and Mysql get the an other one (most of the time 3307).

Vtiger will always try to connect to a database to the port 3306 (unless you change it in the code). So you can change the sql-mode in "/bin/mysqlx.x.x/my.cfg" as you want, and see it changed in the MySQL console, but Vtiger won't be trying to connect to it, but to 3306.

I spent way more time on this issue than it deserved, mostly because I felt that changing the "sql-mode" in the .cfg file to change an "sql_mode" variable was weird and was the issues, idk why MySQL made it like that but that's not user friendly at all.